# How to get the number of milliseconds represented by a java.sql.Time?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mariadb

I have a `java.sql.Time` `(00:04:24)` from which I want to get the number of milliseconds (or seconds):

```
ResultSet rs = ...;
java.sql.Time time = rs.getTime("DURATION");
long millis = time.getTime();
```

But the result are `-3336000` instead of `264000`.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G3VB.png) to see my output.

Why isn't the output `264000`?

Comment: What is the database column type?

Comment: If the server sends back text `"00:04:24"` as the column value, the JDBC driver might parse that as being in the current time zone, and if your time zone is CEST, i.e. GMT+1, then `1970-01-01T00:04:24` (264000) becomes `1969-12-31T23:04:24Z` (-3336000)

Comment: Try this instead: `java.time.LocalTime.parse(rs.getString("DURATION")).toSecondOfDay()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the modern JDBC version, you can use :

```
LocalTime time = rs.getObject("DURATION", LocalTime.class);
long millis = time.toSecondOfDay() * 1000 + time.get(MILLI_OF_SECOND);
```

About the calculation of milliseconds, unfortunately, there are no method to get the Milliseconds of the day, for that I used that way.

Or as suggested by [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685351/how-to-get-the-number-of-milliseconds-represented-by-a-java-sql-time/60685611?noredirect=1#comment107381813_60685611) :

```
long millis = time.toNanoOfDay() / 1000000
```

Comment: Why not `long millis = time.toNanoOfDay() / 1000000`?